# Kotlin: Activity doesn't support ViewModelStoreOwner

Tags: android, kotlin

I used `Activity()`, not `AppcompatActivity()` to make transparent background.

```
class CommentActivity : Activity() {
```

And when I tried to create `ViewModel`, I can't use `this` as ViewModelStoreOwner.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try implementing the `ViewModelStoreOwner` interface:

```
 class MainActivity : Activity(), ViewModelStoreOwner{
    companion object{
        var VIEWMODEL_STORE:ViewModelStore? = null
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val testViewModel:TestViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TestViewModel::class.java)

        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.test_text)
        textView.text = testViewModel.testMessage()
        Log.i("MainActivity",testViewModel.testMessage())
    }

    override fun getViewModelStore(): ViewModelStore {
        if(VIEWMODEL_STORE == null){
            VIEWMODEL_STORE = ViewModelStore()
        }
        return VIEWMODEL_STORE!!
    }

}
```

The viewModel class stays without changes:

```
class TestViewModel:ViewModel() {

    fun testMessage():String = "From TestViewModel ${hashCode()}"
}
```

Comment: This implementation lacks the part where it calls `viewModelStore.clear()` when activity is being destroyed while not changing configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You have to at least extend [`ComponentActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity), native [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) doesn't contain any support for androidx components.